# Correct way to include custom javascript when using Zurb Foundation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

Numerous times now I've come up against problems when trying to add my own jQuery to a Foundation project.

Is this something to do with the way Foundation uses "no-conflict"? What is the correct procedure to adding ones own scripts?

I've tried including a call to a scripts.js file after the call to foundation.min.js but some very simple slideToggle calls are not running at all. Yet when I remove reference to foundation.min.js all works fine.

I've also had issues with external script files.

Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added my custom js script to the very end of the list of scripts before the closing body tag, and before the $(document).foundation();. I also stored it in the js/vendor directory. In my paste below, I've stored everything in a global directory; just look for your own js directory.

```
<script src="global/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.cookie.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js"></script>

<script src="global/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

<!-- My Custom Script!!!! -->
<script src="global/js/vendor/custom.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You didn't mention if yo'ure using Zurb Foundation 4; if you are then note that it uses Zepto (instead of jQuery) by default except for browsers that don't understand the **proto** call. If you're seeing jQuery functions not work, you may want to comment out the code that sets up Zepto instead of jQuery and then test. Look for the following, also near the bottom of the document:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'global/js/vendor/zepto' : 'global/js/vendor/jquery') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

Replace that with:

```
<!-- <script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'global/js/vendor/zepto' : 'global/js/vendor/jquery') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script> -->

<script src="global/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

And then make sure to store the jquery.js in the appropriate folder. Again, I'm storing my files in a /global directory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Will for your answer, yes I've just changed to Foundation 4, will give your ideas a go and report back!

Comment: Thanks Will, doing all that for Foundation 4 seems to have done the trick. I got rid of the zepto call and included jquery manually. Thanks!

Comment: Hey onjegolders-- just curious if this answer worked out for you?

Comment: Hi Will, yes thanks seems to work OK, had issues with Zepto and I still find the inclusions a bit unintuitive but all's working now

Comment: I just did the same after a couple of hours of debugging. I use the FancyBox 2 to display some galleries. In Chrome/Firefox etc they worked perfect, IE not however. I ended up tearing down everything from a testpage and build it up again, piece by piece to see what broke the fancybox jquery usage. Came here after trying to understand why. You Sir, made my day :) Thanks! [tag:fancybox]